# Create NSBox runtime example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbox

Please, could you give me examples of how to create the `NSBox` instance runtime to place it inside the `NSView`?

Comment: I’ve added an example that works with garbage collection enabled. Let me know if you want me to fix it so that, when compiled without garbage collection, it doesn’t leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSView *superview = …; // Reference to the view that will contain the box
                       // for instance, [window contentView]

NSUInteger resizeAllMask = (NSViewWidthSizable
    | NSViewHeightSizable
    | NSViewMinXMargin
    | NSViewMaxXMargin
    | NSViewMinYMargin
    | NSViewMaxYMargin);

// This is the box. We use an autoresizing mask so that it occupies
// the entire superview 
NSBox *box = [[NSBox alloc] initWithFrame:[superview bounds]];
[box setAutoresizingMask:resizeAllMask];
[box setBoxType:NSBoxPrimary];
[box setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
[box setTitle:@"This is a box"];

// This is the box' content view. It represents the box contents.
// By default, a box autoresizes its content view so that it occupies
// the entire box
NSView *boxContentView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
[box setContentView:boxContentView];

// For example, we add a text field to the box' content view
NSRect textRect = {{0,0}, {100,20}};
NSTextField *textField = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:textRect];
[textField setStringValue:@"Hey there"];
[boxContentView addSubview:textField];

[superview addSubview:box];
```

Comment: I have compiled the code without garbage collection support and there are no leaks for all allocated objects are being released:
 [box removeFromSuperview];
 [box release];
 [textField release];
 [boxContentView release];
Thank you very much!